# What is the best way to load JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC world and I want to know which way is the best to load JavaScript codes into the project:

1. using script tag directly in the page.
2. using  `BundleCollection` class to add scripts.
3. using `jQuery.getScript` method to load the scripts dynamically.

and want to know what is the difference between them.

Comment: I don't think posting questions in bold text should be getting more answers...

Comment: BundleConfig.cs

is the best....

Comment: I just made it bold to look more nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends upon the usage.

If you want to avoid waiting for all the javascript to load before your page fires the ready event, then you may use jQuery.getScript.

Using the script tag directly will ensure that the script is available and executed before the browser parser proceeds to the next line.

Lastly, in ASP.NET, using the BundleCollection can help you optimise your JS, in a way that it allows you to bundle, compress and even minify the content before serving. This can result in quicker loading times if you have a lot of JS files on your page.

Comment: is it necessary to add development version of scripts to BundleCollection  ,what if I add minified version,what will append or is it a bad practice ?

Comment: In production I would recommend you to use minified versions of your scripts.
BundleCollection would still be useful as it will compress them together and serve a single file.

Comment: one more question.is it possible to load css files using * character like :---> "~/Content/bootstrap*" ?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can try to wrote the complete file name. Thanks. Please accept this answer if it solves your problem.